# Best method for Auto scrolling to previous place without jquery (PHP and Javascript)

Tags: javascript, php

I have done my homework and seen allot of different methods of accomplishing this. But what is the most effective way that is cross-browser error "proof".

Some things I have tried...

```
body.onload = function(){ 
  window.scrollTo(0,<?php echo $_POST['scrolltext'];?>);
};
```

With scrolltext coming from a hidden input filled by a `document.getElementById('scrolltext').value = window.pageYOffset || docElem.scrollTop || body.scrollTop`

Also...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#<?php echo $_POST['site']; ?>').scrollIntoView(true);
});
```

with many otherr forms of this, where the posted site being a ID linked by php on the page based on the button pushed. But I found Jquery's methods very unreliable and Ipad's especially seem to hate everything to do with jquery(especially panels)...

So i figured the best way to do it would be javascript? some PHP methods I cant really think of?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: PHP is going to do nothing to aid you here outside of dynamically populating javascript like you are doing.  Maybe look into jQuery Mobile if mobile is your target device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Scroll to the top of a document

```
$("html, body").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, 300);
```

Scroll to the top of an element

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#itemid").offset().top }, 800);
```

Scroll to the top of a specified element

```
var itemid = $("#daitemid2").val(); //method 1 
var itemid = $(this).attr("itemid"); //method 2
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $("#itemid"+itemid+").offset().top }, 800);
```